# Multilingual website in .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I want to create dual language website which is using SQL server 2008, On my site some pages are static and some fetching data from SQL database inserted by Super admin. I find various example to user Localization and Globalization but none of them using data controls like Gridview, Datalist etc. I don't want to use separate database for other languages.

Comment: what have you tried so far? and what's wrong with localization and globalization? have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can guarantee that all strings that can be localized correctly (excluding user input via data entry forms) is by creating *some sort* of resource that contains translations for all of these strings.

You could also use a translation API of some sort I guess but we all know what translation programs are like: terrible.

The .Net framework has built-in globalization and localization features, one of which is through using resources. There are MSDN articles on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).